# What's the priority for function composition in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I saw this code on my textbook:

```
double :: (Num a) => a -> a
double x = x * 2

map (double.double) [1,2,3,4]
```

What I don't get is that if functional composition operation have the highest priority, why use parentheses to include double.double? If I remove those parentheses, I get error message. So what's exactly is functional composition's priority?

Comment: I think the important part here is: functions take precedence over operators. So `f a b + g c d` is always `(f a b) + (g c d)`..

Comment: In GHCi, `:info (.)` will tell you that `(.)` is declared with `infix 9 .`, a right-associative operator with precedence 9.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of the built-in operators' respective precedences and fixities can be found in the [Haskell Report section 4.4.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html). In particular, `.` and `!!` have precedence 9, which is the highest among *operators*. However, function application is not an operator. Function application is specifically designed to have precedence higher than *any* operator, so

```
map (double.double) [1,2,3,4]
```

This is applying the function `double . double` to each element of the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

```
map double.double [1,2,3,4]
```

This is attempting to compose the functions `map double` and `double [1, 2, 3, 4]`, which is unlikely to be successful (though it is not technically impossible).

Comment: Though application isn't an operator, you can pretty much imagine it is, with "word break" as its symbol, and it acts like it is `infixl 10`. Similarly, as-patterns `var@pat` act like they are `infixr 11`, and the function type constructor `(->)` acts like it is `infixr -1`.

Comment: @HTNW `info (->)` actually reports ```infixr 0 `(->)` ```

Comment: @Ben [Yes, that's a bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15235).

Comment: You said: "`map double.double [1,2,3,4]` This is attempting to compose the functions `map double` and `double [1, 2, 3, 4]`". But if `map double.double [1,2,3,4]` == `map (.) double double [1,2,3,4]`, why is this not the same as attemping to apply `map (.) double` to `double` and finally to `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: @pbsb `map double.double [1,2,3,4]` is equivalent to `(.) (map double) (double [1,2,3,4])`, not to `map (.) double double [1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Precedence (and associativity) are ways of resolving the ambiguity between multiple infix operators in an expression. If there are two operators next to an operand, precedence (and associativity) tells you which of them takes the operand as an argument and which of them takes the other applied-operator expression as an argument. For example, in the expression `1 + 2 * 3`, the `2` is next to both `+` and `*`. The higher precedence of `*` means that `*` gets the `2` as its left argument, while `+` takes the whole `2 * 3` sub-expression as its right argument.

However that's not the case in `map double.double [1, 2, 3, 4]`. There's only one operator, with two operands on either side, so there's no question for precedence to answer for us. The two operands are `map double` and `double [1, 2, 3, 4]`; operands are *sequences* of one or more terms, not only the immediate left and right terms. Where there's more than one term the sequence is parsed as simple chained function application (i.e. `a b c d` is `((a b) c) d`).

Another way to think of it is that there is an "adjacency operator" which has higher precedence than can be assigned to anything else, and is invisibly present between any two non-operator terms (but not anywhere else). In this way of thinking `map double.double [1, 2, 3, 4]` is really something like `map @ double . double @ [1, 2, 3, 4]` (where I've written this "adjacency operator" as `@`). Since `@` has higher precedence than `.`, this is `(map @ double) . (double @ [1, 2, 3, 4])`.<sup>1</sup>

Whichever way you choose to interpret it, there is a simple consequence. It is simply impossible for *any* applied operator expression to be passed as an argument in non-operator function application unless there are parentheses around the operator application. If there is an operator in an expression outside any parentheses, then the outermost layer of the expression is always going to be an operator application.

---

<sup>1</sup> This adjacency operator explanation seems to be pretty common. I personally think it is a poor explanation for how to parse expressions, since you need to partially parse an expression to know where to insert the adjacency operators.

It's often called the "whitespace operator", which is even more confusing since not every piece of whitespace represents this operator, and you don't always need whitespace for it to be there. e.g. `length"four" + 1`